# Get Magento 2 collection based on final_price

Tags: collections, magento2

I have the following code to get a Magento 2 product collection:

```
<?php namespace Qxs\Related\Block;

class Related extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
  )
  {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }

  public function getProductCollection()
  {
    try {

      $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');

      $range_percentage = 35;
      $price_temp = round($product->getFinalPrice() / 100 * $range_percentage);
      $price_from = $product->getFinalPrice() - $price_temp;
      $price_to = $product->getFinalPrice() + $price_temp;

      $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();

      $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories])
        ->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s >= %s', ['min_price', $price_from])
        ->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s <= %s', ['min_price', $price_to])
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $product->getId()])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
        ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
        ->setPageSize(5);

      return $collection;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

**Code above is updated with a working example**

It will return a result with addtofieldfilter 'price' but it does not work with final_price attribute. I need to sort based on final_price because configurable products don't have a price. The code returns: invalid attribute name.

How can I filter on price range in final_price attribute?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final_price is part of the price index tables, so you can't work with it the same way as you would do with fields and attributes. You need to join in the price index to be able to filter and sort based on final_price. Luckily, Magento has added a few nifty functions for us to use on the product collection; `addPriceDataFieldFilter()` and `addFinalPrice()`.

**Solution**

To be able to achieve the logic you describe above, you would want to change your code to something like this:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories])
    ->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s >= %s', ['final_price', $price_from])
    ->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s <= %s', ['final_price', $price_to])
    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => $product->getId()])
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
    ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
    ->setPageSize(5);
```

Note the order of the functions. You must always call `addFinalPrice()` after all of the `addPriceDataFieldFilter()` or else the filter won't be applied.

**Bonus**

If you want to sort by final_price, you can add following code after `addFinalPrice()`:

```
$collection->getSelect()->order('price_index.final_price ASC');
```

**References**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.9/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php#L1465
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.9/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php#L2265

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to work. However, I found that final_price like the price is empty for configurable products. I think I should use minimal price for the query, but it is returning error generating content.

Comment: Attribute min_price is working with the code above, thx. I have updated my code with a working example.